# Using the HTML5 date input element with android

Tags: android, html, date, cordova, trigger.io

The element `<input type="date" />` cannot be activated.

When I click on the fields on the emulator it doesn't show me the entrance date but the android keyboard.

Comment: I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865378/how-to-make-the-html5-input-type-date-trigger-the-native-datepicker-on-android/16866240#16866240

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html

It tells you which html5 input types and attributes work on each browser. It looks like **the datepicker isn't working** for most Androids, and thus it would show as a simple text input.

Comment: So I have to use javascript for dates

Comment: I'm 99% sure about that. Html5 is not mature enough yet.

Comment: @MedAmine if this solved your question in any way, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I guess he wanted a factory feature, as mobiscroll is javascript based. However, it is a good alternative

Comment: Update: newer devices like Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4 do support this Element.

Comment: Ok then, I made the proper changes. However, this kind of feature isn't related to the smartphone, but the browser, so I expect S3/4 carry a newer browser made by samsung.

Comment: I'm using this for android in ionic app. It works fine but I make this input as hidden and firing click event when user click on div so it's not working. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Trigger.io's UI module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/ui.html) to use the native Android date / time picker with a regular HTML5 input. Doing that does require using the overall framework though (so won't work as a regular mobile web page).

You can see before and after screenshots in this blog post:
http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/11/16/new-feature-roundup-native-date-time-picker-analytics-with-flurry-android-events/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [How to make the HTML5 input type 'date' trigger the native datepicker on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865378/how-to-make-the-html5-input-type-date-trigger-the-native-datepicker-on-android)

[mobiscroll.com](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/datetime#mode=scroller) offers a nice polyfill.