# ionic input type="date" not working on android apk version below 19

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework

input type="date" is working fine on my device 4.2 and working on 4.2 above versions.
but in lower versions of android input type="date" is not working as expected and taking input as text.
how can i solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the HTML5 date input element with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137567/using-the-html5-date-input-element-with-android)

Comment: Have you used input type on native EditText or Html Input on browser ?